# Using $set and $setOnInsert during upsert

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-java

I'm trying to update a collection in mongodb and if a field exists, will insert it. I'm not so sure how can I do that with the upsert option.

```
MongoCollection<Document> docs = mongoDb.getCollection("users");
Bson filterQuery = new Document("userId", userId).append("fileType", fileType);
Bson updateQuery = new Document("$set", new Document("fileType", fileType).append("fileName", fileName).append("fileSize", fileSize).append("userId", userId).append("lastModifiedTimestamp", new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis())));
updateQuery.append("$setOnInsert", new Document("creationTimestamp", new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis())));
docs.updateOne(filterQuery, updateQuery, (new UpdateOptions()).upsert(true));
```

This is not working. I'm not updating the same fields for $set and $setOnInsert but not sure why this isn't working. Any thoughts?

Comment: Are you trying to update the lastModifiedTimestamp every time you do an update, or what are you trying to achieve ? I think you if the record does not exist you are trying to insert the creationTimestamp, if record exist you only try to update the lastModifiedTimestamp, I am correct ?

Comment: Yes exactly. Trying to update the lastModifiedTimestamp every time I do an update.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tried to use the following config, I have some compilation errors in your code that I fix below.

```
public class StackOverflowApp {

   public static void main (String[] args){

    MongoClientOptions options = MongoClientOptions.builder().connectionsPerHost(100).build();
    MongoClient client = new MongoClient(new ServerAddress(), options);
    MongoDatabase db = client.getDatabase("test").withReadPreference(ReadPreference.secondary());

    String userId = "myUser2";
    String fileType = "fileType2";
    String fileName = "fileName";
    String fileSize = "fileSize";
    MongoCollection<Document> docs = db.getCollection("users");
    Bson filterQuery = new Document("userId", userId).append("fileType", fileType);
    Bson updateQuery = new Document("$set", new Document("fileType", fileType).append("fileName", fileName).append("fileSize", fileSize).append("userId", userId).append("lastModifiedTimestamp", new Date(System.currentTimeMillis())));
    ((Document)updateQuery).append("$setOnInsert", new Document("creationTimestamp", new Date(System.currentTimeMillis())));
    docs.updateOne(filterQuery, updateQuery, (new UpdateOptions()).upsert(true));
    }
}
```

If I run the first time I insert this one.

```
"_id" : ObjectId("570c6f2105c7937ac1c794cb"),
"fileType" : "fileType2",
"userId" : "myUser2",
"fileName" : "fileName",
"fileSize" : "fileSize",
"lastModifiedTimestamp" : ISODate("2016-04-12T03:44:33.454Z"),
"creationTimestamp" : ISODate("2016-04-12T03:44:33.454Z")
```

Second time only lastModifiedTimestamp is updated

```
"_id" : ObjectId("570c6f2105c7937ac1c794cb"),
"fileType" : "fileType2",
"userId" : "myUser2",
"fileName" : "fileName",
"fileSize" : "fileSize",
"lastModifiedTimestamp" : ISODate("2016-04-12T03:44:59.947Z"),
"creationTimestamp" : ISODate("2016-04-12T03:44:33.454Z")
```

I think that is what you were tried to achieve.

Comment: Did you use java.util.Date? I'm not able to save the timstamps for some reason.